# Firebase how to remove key pushing element

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, nosql

I got [database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZMp6.png)

When I add new user tree using push(), a key appears as a parent. And then I have to get user data, but this key interfere. How can I rename this element of tree or get username through the key or replace this part without key or use not the push() but something else that don't create key parent or maybe I can get necessary key using currentUser

Comment: can you show the code that you have done so far?

Comment: I recieved it
`app.database().ref('users/').child(newName).set(newUser)`

Answer (score 0):

I just recieved it, it was easier than I thought
`app.database().ref('users/').child(newName).set(newUser)`